# Are there ssh and scp tasks available for phing?

Tags: php, deployment, phing

I would like to do remote deployment from my build machine onto a server. The remoting can be done via ssh commands from a script, but I would rather use phing and a deploy.xml file that would do the automation.

What alternatives do I have to do ssh (and also scp) tasks from within a phing build file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you really need phing, then afaik there's only exec. If you are open for other tools, have a look at [capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) and my answer in "[Setting up a PHP web project, the infrastructure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220638/setting-up-a-php-web-project-the-infrastructure#225524)".

Comment: Thanks... I used capistrano in the past and I'm happy with it. However, it means that your team now needs to understand 2 languages (PHP and a bit of Ruby). I would rather go for one solution, but we all must be pragmatic...

Comment: That's a true concern. However, a good programmer will learn to handle a capistrano makefile in less than a day. Trust me. For example, I don't do any Ruby usually and I've coded tasks with namespaces in less than eight hours. The docs for capistrano are pretty awesome.

Comment: You don't answer the question which is to do public key authentication using Phing tasks.

Comment: @amateur barista: Well, for starters, I answered that there is always `<exec />`. I then provided an alternative which does it right out of the box. And you can run phing tasks through capistrano too.

Answer (score 15):

[SCPTask](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/ScpTask.html) in Phing:

> copies files to and from a remote host using scp. This task requires the **[PHP SSH2 extension](http://web.archive.org/web/20101219161808/http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)** to function...

Answer (score 9):

I came across a [SCP and SSH tasks](http://phing.info/trac/browser/branches/2.4/classes/phing/tasks/ext) for Phing yesterday. You will also need to follow the instructions for [installing SSH2 for PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.setup.php). I wasn't able to get the tasks to work straight out of the box, you might. I modified my copy, if you need I can provide.

Comment: If you are using WAMP, all you need to do is left-click the WAMP icon, go to PHP -> PHP Extensions, then enable php_ss2.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem about a year ago and back then i could not find a task. I ended up doing a exec task, this way it was all in the xml file.

```
<exec command="scp -i keys/id_rsa myfile user@$server:myfile" dir="." />
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but there seems to be multiple broken links and some misinformation.

[**ScpTask**: http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs60.html](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs60.html)

[**SshTask**: http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs60.htm](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs60.html)

Answer (score 1):

For [SemanticScuttle](http://semanticscuttle.sourceforge.net/), we use [rsync to deploy](http://semanticscuttle.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=semanticscuttle/sc;a=blob;f=build.xml;hb=HEAD) release files to the SourceForge server - also via exec. Rsync understands ssh.

Answer (score 0):

For ssh, there's the ssh2 PECL extension and then Phing has the [ssh](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs63.html) and [scp](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apcs62.html) tasks.

1. On a Mac, install libssh2 via Homebrew. On Linux, use your package manager.
2. `sudo pecl install pecl.php.net/ssh2-0.12`

You can now do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="test" default="test">
  <target name="test">
    <ssh username="vagrant" password="vagrant" host="192.168.123.456"
        command="pwd" property="pwd" display="false" />
    <echo>The current working directory is ${pwd}</echo>
  </target>
</project>
```